# Advanced conditional in Category_Archive Channel to show "active" entry (using Structure)

Tags: structure, categories, advanced-conditionals

I have wrapped this in a Snippet to advance the parsing order, but I cannot seem to get this to work...hence the {?}.

```
<ul class="accordion">


{exp:channel:category_archive channel="hurricane" style="linear" dynamic="on" }

           {categories}
        {if segment_3 == '{?}'}<li class="active"> {if:else} <li class="">{/if}
          <div class="title">
            <h5>{category_name}</h5>
          </div>{/categories}
          <div class="content">
           {entry_titles}
           <a href="{path='members/hurricane/'}">{title}</a><br />
           {/entry_titles}
          </div>

        </li>
         {/exp:channel:category_archive}
```

Comment: I don't believe 'dynamic=on' is a thing, according to the docs anyway. Bit more on what you're trying to achieve with errors or issue would help.

Comment: This code sits in a sidebar on a single entry's template and it simply should highlight the current entry by adding an active class to the <li> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout may have to change because EE doesn't yet know if the title is inside the category. If you can transfer the conditional inside the entry_titles you may have better luck.

```
{entry_titles}
{if segment_x == {url_title}}do something{/if}
{/entry_titles}
```

EE category stuff can be a pita and I've often used gwCode categories. You do get more flexibility and control but its a case by case thing.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use:

```
segment_3 == {category_URL_title}
```

Assuming you're looking to see if current category is in the URL.

I try and avoid if:else and simply use 2 simples instead or switchee.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, but I'm not looking for the current category - just the current entry..